# Tagging applications so Spotlight shows them correctly? "itunes" suggested "podcasts" on macOS Catalina

Tags: itunes, macos-catalina, spotlight

So, I just booted up Spotlight and wrote itunes into it, on a macOS Catalina, cos, you know, muscle-memory.

Pressed enter without thinking too much about it. **Podcasts** opened. The mind boggles.

So, what is the method for adding identifier tags to .app files so that I can call them. A bad-to-useless example would be that I'd type **musik** and would get the Music app.

Is there something I can do in the Finder about this stuff?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your index isn't populated completely.  Either it is still indexing after the upgrade to Catalina (?), or you haven't tried to use these apps and so they're not inxexed yet in the preferred results

[image: screenshot shot showing itunes and music and podcasts in search results]